# Icon little issue

Tags: c#, wpf, icons

Finally the hour has come, the release folder is not empty now, the last touches are done. I've noticed this behavior and was wondering if someone else had this problem and how to solve it:

[image]
Ok here.

[image]
Ok here.

[image]
Not okey here. (Windows Explorer bar)

The icon comes with a variety of sizes, and it is set as resource in VS solution.

It's not very important but it gives a very poor image of the app. Is there any easy solution?

Answer (score 0):

From your image, it appears that you do not have the icon in the relevant size for the Windows Explorer. Do you have a 16 x 16 pixel image in your icon?

I believe that the main size used in Windows are 16 x 16, 32 x 32 and 48 x 48. If the icon will be used in the Folder pane of Windows Explorer, icons can grow up to 256 x 256... maybe even 512 x 512 now, I'm not quite sure.

So if you can provide an icon with the 3 main sizes, you *should* be ok... these are the sizes that I have used in my icons and I have never had the problem that you show.